# Disable vim mode in PhpStorm in debug

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ideavim

Is it possible to disable vim in certain windows/modes? For instance in debugger it's a bit annoying, also when editing cell values in Database mode it's not perfect.

Another question if a tab can switch to command mode when I'm about to navigate to another tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible in IdeaVim 0.50. There is a feature request that partially covers what you're describing: [VIM-765 Option to disable plugin in dialog boxes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-765). Feel free to vote for this feature and/or file new requests at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM.

You can remap `<Tab>` to `gt` using standard Vim mapping commands. Put them into your ~/.ideavimrc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re. the tab question...that's not what I meant. Currently IDE remembers in which tab I'm in command or insert mode. I'd like it NOT to remember that and simply switch to command when I focus that tab